# Using OpenTK in a Gtk# window

Tags: c#, gtk#, xamarin-studio, opentk

I'm trying to use OpenTK via a window in GTK#. Xamarin Studio doesn't have any native GL controls loaded normally, so I tried loading [GTKSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glwidget/) directly from the DLL.

[image: Loading the GTKSharp DLL]

Then dragging over the control

[image: Dragging over the control]

Results in an error.

[image: The Error]

Has anyone managed to get around this error? Or have a different approach for loading a GL control into a GTK# window.

Comment: I guess you are using GLWidget from http://sourceforge.net/projects/glwidget/ is that right?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that piece of information off. Yes, I'm using GLWidget.